# Edit a .gziped log text file in C#

Tags: c#

I receive logs which are .gz (zipped) and contain text files.

One field in the logs needs to be edited, present on every row, to contain some other data then what is currently present in the logs.

My thinking so far is to:

1. Unzip file
2. Read it
3. Edit it
4. Write it
5. Rezip it

But I guess there is a better way to do this, is there any on-the-fly reading/editing from .gz log files available in C#?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to work at the bit-level, the method you suggest is the correct approach.

incase you are unfamiliar with the .Net libraries for this, here is a code project article.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/GZipStream.aspx

Comment: But he's talking about unzipping the whole file up-front whereas you're suggesting streaming through it between a compressed input and output stream aren't you?

Comment: GZipStream actually gives you the stream of data so you don't actually unzip the file first.  Otherwise correct.